# Massive diff. between Training and Testing accuracy: just overfitting or am I missing somth obvious?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

I am using Tensorflow to adopt the Convolution and Pooling techniques to a deep learning project that is unrelated to images and uses a simple numeric dataset as input. I realize that it's a bit apples and oranges, but I quite like the approach of 'sliding a window' over a set of observations and extracting a set of features out of it, even though the observations aren't exactly pixels, so I wanted to give it a try.

So far I am getting very disappointing Testing Accuracy, and I would have given up by now, except that the Training Accuracy and Loss seem to be performing reasonably well and respond in a sensible way to various adjustments in hyperparameters.

I am well aware of the possibility of overfitting, but could it really be so bad that I would achieve 90% accuracy on Training and remain stuck at 25% accuracy on Testing? My data has 4 classes, so 25% accuracy in testing is basically purely random outcomes. I am wondering if I'm just missing something completely obvious here?

I'm trying to analyze my Graph in TensorBoard and as far as I can understand I don't see anything wrong with with the computation of Training and Testing accuracies. The only thing I don't understand is why Training and Testing input queues are listed on the side and don't seem to be connected with anything, but I can see from running the code and logging from inside the code that TF reads the appropriate training and testing data in batches.

My network quite simple -- 1 convolution layer + 1 fully connected layer + 1 readout layer. Each input row has 480 columns and the idea is to keep it that way, instead of forming an AxB matrix. I then 'slide' a 30x1 window across this line with the given stride. I am extracting 50 features out of the convolution layer and 100 features out of the fully connected layer. I split the original dataset 80/20 for training and testing via `sklearn.cross_validation.train_test_split`

Do I have too many degrees of freedom that the network simply overfits and memorizes the training data and remains useless for the testing data? Or am I not evaluating the Test Accuracy properly?

Testing Accuracy is calculated as follows:

```
    dateLbl_batch, feature_batch, label_batch = sess.run([dateLblTest, featuresTest, labelsTest])

    acc, summary = sess.run([accuracyTest, summary_test], feed_dict={X: feature_batch, Y_: label_batch})

    i += 1
    summary_writer.add_summary(summary, i)
```

Where accuracyTest is defined like this:

```
with tf.name_scope('AccuracyTest'):
    accuracyTest = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(tf.equal(
        tf.argmax(Y, 1),
        tf.argmax(Y_, 1)), tf.float32))
```

and Y_ are the labels loaded from the Test dataset and Y is the output of the Readout Layer:

```
Y = tf.matmul(h_fc1, W_fc2, name='ReadOut_Layer') + b_fc2
```

Here's the relevant part of my code that has it all together:

```
    TS = 480
    TL = 4

    def weight_variable(shape):
        initial = tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.1)
        return tf.Variable(initial)
    def bias_variable(shape):
        initial = tf.constant(0.1, shape=shape)
        return tf.Variable(initial)
    def conv2d(x, W, sX, sY):
        return tf.nn.conv2d(x, W, strides=[1, sX, sY, 1], padding='SAME')
    def pool_fn(x, kX, kY, sX, sY):
        return tf.nn.max_pool(x, ksize=[1, kX, kY, 1], strides=[1, sX, sY, 1], padding='SAME')

    Y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, TL], name='pl_labels')
    X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, TS], name='pl_x')

    # Convolution Parameters
    frame_x = 480
    frame_y = 1
    wnd_x = 30
    wnd_y = 1
    features_l1 = 50
    features_lFC = 100
    conv_stride_x = 1
    conv_stride_y = 1
    pool_krn_x = 2
    pool_krn_y = 1
    pool_stride_x = 2
    pool_stride_y = 1
    fc_x = int(frame_x / pool_krn_x)
    fc_y = int(frame_y / pool_krn_y)

    # 1st Layer
    x_conv = tf.reshape(X, [-1,frame_x,frame_y,1])
    W_conv1 = weight_variable([wnd_x, wnd_y, 1, features_l1])
    b_conv1 = bias_variable([features_l1])
    h_conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(x_conv, W_conv1, conv_stride_x, conv_stride_y) + b_conv1)
    h_pool1 = pool_fn(h_conv1, pool_krn_x, pool_krn_y, pool_stride_x, pool_stride_y)

    # Fully Connected Layer
    W_fc1 = weight_variable([fc_x * fc_y * features_l1, features_lFC])
    b_fc1 = bias_variable([features_lFC])
    h_pool2_flat = tf.reshape(h_pool1, [-1, fc_x*fc_y*features_l1])
    h_fc1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h_pool2_flat, W_fc1) + b_fc1)

    # Readout Layer
    W_fc2 = weight_variable([features_lFC, TL])
    b_fc2 = bias_variable([TL])
    Y = tf.matmul(h_fc1, W_fc2, name='ReadOut_Layer') + b_fc2

    dateLbl, features, labels = input_pipeline(fileNameTrain, batch_size, try_epochs)
    dateLblTest, featuresTest, labelsTest = input_pipeline(fileNameTest, batch_size, 1)

    with tf.name_scope('SoftMaxModel'):
        myModel = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=Y_, logits=Y, name='SoftMaxModel')
    with tf.name_scope('LossFn'):
        lossFn = tf.reduce_mean(myModel, name = 'LossFn')
    with tf.name_scope('Optimizer'):
         train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-4, name='AdamConst').minimize(lossFn, name='MinimizeLossFn')
    with tf.name_scope('AccuracyTrain'):
        accuracyTrain = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(tf.equal(
            tf.argmax(Y, 1),
            tf.argmax(Y_, 1)), tf.float32))
    with tf.name_scope('AccuracyTest'):
        accuracyTest = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(tf.equal(
            tf.argmax(Y, 1),
            tf.argmax(Y_, 1)), tf.float32))

    a1 = tf.summary.histogram("Model", myModel)
    a2 = tf.summary.scalar("Loss", lossFn)
    a3 = tf.summary.scalar("AccuracyTrain", accuracyTrain)
    a4 = tf.summary.scalar("AccuracyTest", accuracyTest)

    summary_train = tf.summary.merge([a1, a2, a3])
    summary_test = tf.summary.merge([a4])

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        summary_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(logs_path, sess.graph)

        gInit = tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
        lInit = tf.local_variables_initializer().run()

        coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
        threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)

        ############################ TRAINING ############################
        try:
            i = 0
            acCumTrain = 0

            while not coord.should_stop():
                dateLbl_batch, feature_batch, label_batch = sess.run([dateLbl, features, labels])

                _, acc, summary = sess.run([train_step, accuracyTrain, summary_train], feed_dict={X: feature_batch, Y_: label_batch})

                i += 1
                summary_writer.add_summary(summary, i)
                acCumTrain += acc

        except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
            acCumTrain /= i
            print('-------------- Finished Training ---------------')

        finally:
            coord.request_stop()

        coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
        threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)

        ############################ TESTING ############################
        try:

            i = 0
            acCumTest = 0

            while not coord.should_stop():

                dateLbl_batch, feature_batch, label_batch = sess.run([dateLblTest, featuresTest, labelsTest])

                acc, summary = sess.run([accuracyTest, summary_test], feed_dict={X: feature_batch, Y_: label_batch})

                i += 1
                summary_writer.add_summary(summary, i)
                acCumTest += acc

        except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
            acCumTest /= i
            print('-------------- Finished Testing  ---------------')
        finally:
            coord.request_stop()

        print('Training Accuracy: {:.2f} Testing Accuracy: {:.2f}'.format(acCumTrain, acCumTest))
        coord.join(threads)
```

Here are the screenshots of training and testing accuracy from TensorBoard -- looks promising in Training, but just random noise in Testing!

[image: Training/Testing Accuracy and Loss]

Here is the overall Graph:
[image: Full Graph]

And here is the zoom of the Graph that shows how Training and Testing Accuracy are calculated:
[image: Graph Fragment]

Comment: The question has detailed description of the code and nothing about the "simple numeric dataset as input", which likely is much more important than the code. What is the size and structure of the dataset? What is the content of the 480-sized input vector? How is the data encoded? Why do you believe that the convolutional assumption is good for this dataset? etc. It *seems* that you're doing a task that is classification of a time-series, but it's not clear, and the task details are important - black box approach of data-in-data-out doesn't always work, as you now have experimentally verified..

Comment: Ah, you are right. Of course I don't know yet that the Convolution approach is appropriate, just trying it out experimentally to see where I can get. The data set is indeed time-series, where each row has 480 observations that are normalized -- in one version to range of [-1 to +1] and in the other to [0 to +1]. The first version uses tanh() in the model for non-linearity, while the second uses RELU() Frankly no difference. I prob. have too few observations (about 1,600) in total and I tried running on too many epochs, so training is overfitting...

Comment: Next step I will try to add some randomization to the data to create more observations and reduce significantly the # of epochs. The underlying problem is probably that the task is non-applicable in the first place, or something is not right with the data, but I wanted to make sure I also wasn't missing something very obvious in the construction of the graph, because TensorFlow examples are very tailor-made for the pre-packaged MNIST dataset, whereas this one is quite different and is based on numeric CSV input. So I just wanted to make sure I wasn't doing something wrong in the code too..

Answer (score 0):

Looks like overfitting to me. Try adding dropout and weight decay and see what changes. Maybe even increase the capacity, while applying regularization, by adding more layers. If this does not help you should take a look at the data. Maybe your training/test set is too different. Then augmentations might help.

Comment: Yes, tried dropout, doesn't make any difference. Never tried weight decay, but will give it a try. Indeed, next step is to increase the dataset, because I think I just overdid it with epochs

Answer (score 0):

The numbers you give in the comments make me think that it's definitely overfitting. For example, MNIST has twice as many features as you but 35 times as many training examples.

I think it's also useful to get a sense for how many weights (parameters) you have -- that surprised me when I started using CNNs. Your first conv layer has 30*50 featues = 1500, which isn't so bad. But then you have 50*480/2=12000 INPUTS to your fully-connected layer, which turn into 48000 features in your FC. That's a pretty big matrix for the size of your problem.

You could actually make your parameter space a lot smaller by adding a conv-layer or two, along with pooling layers.

Other ways to make your parameter-space smaller: decrease the size of your conv-filter from 50 to 10, or use dimension-reduction techniques like PCA.

Finally, don't forget that there's actually a Conv1d function that suits your use much better.